# How to implement oval GradientPaint?

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d, affinetransform, radial-gradients

We know that there are a class named `RadialGradientPaint` in Java and we can use it to have a gradient painting for circle.

But I want to have an oval (ellipse) `GradientPaint`. How to implement oval `GradientPaint`?

Answer (score 13):

Use an [`AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) when drawing the `RadialGradientPaint`.  This would require a scale instance of the transform.  It might end up looking something like this:

[image: OvalGradientPaint]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.MultipleGradientPaint.CycleMethod;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class OvalGradientPaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // the GUI as seen by the user (without frame)
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 3, 2, 3));

                gui.add(new OvalGradientPaintSurface());
                gui.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Oval Gradient Paint");
                f.add(gui);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
                // in order display the components within it
                f.pack();
                // should be done last, to avoid flickering, moving,
                // resizing artifacts.
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class OvalGradientPaintSurface extends JPanel {

    public int yScale = 150;
    public int increment = 1;
    RadialGradientPaint paint;
    AffineTransform moveToOrigin;

    OvalGradientPaintSurface() {
        Point2D center = new Point2D.Float(100, 100);
        float radius = 90;
        float[] dist = {0.05f, .95f};
        Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.MAGENTA.darker()};
        paint = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors,CycleMethod.REFLECT);
        moveToOrigin = AffineTransform.
                getTranslateInstance(-100d, -100d);
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (increment < 0) {
                    increment = (yScale < 50 ? -increment : increment);
                } else {
                    increment = (yScale > 150 ? -increment : increment);
                }
                yScale += increment;
                repaint();
            }
        };

        Timer t = new Timer(15, listener);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform moveToCenter = AffineTransform.
                getTranslateInstance(getWidth()/2d, getHeight()/2d);
        g2.setPaint(paint);
        double y = yScale/100d;
        double x = 1/y;
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(x, y);

        // We need to move it to the origin, scale, and move back.
        // Counterintutitively perhaps, we concatentate 'in reverse'.
        moveToCenter.concatenate(at);
        moveToCenter.concatenate(moveToOrigin);
        g2.setTransform(moveToCenter);

        // fudge factor of 3 here, to ensure the scaling of the transform
        // does not leave edges unpainted.
        g2.fillRect(-getWidth(), -getHeight(), getWidth()*3, getHeight()*3);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 200);
    }
}
```

**Original image:**  The original static (boring) 'screen shot' of the app.

[image: OvalGradientPaint]

Comment: @trashgod Yeah, it's an 'almost template'(1) I devised for Netbeans.  I simply could not tolerate doing all those statements for a frame SSCCE without throwing in some comments.  1) Have not yet figured how to use it short of copy pasting the text and changing the class name.

Comment: Create: `Tools > Templates > Add`; edit: `Tools > Templates > Open in Editor`; use: `File > New File`, the new template should be in the same category to which it was added; open an existing one to see meta symbols, e.g. ${package} and `${name}`.

Comment: @trashgod Thanks.  That's working better now with the meta symbols. :)

Answer (score 1):

`RadialGradientPaint` provides two ways to paint itself as an ellipse instead of a circle:

1. Upon construction, you can specify a transform for the gradient.  For example, if you provide the following transform: `AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(0.5, 1)`, your gradient will be an upright oval (the x dimension will be half that of the y dimension).
2. Or, you can use the constructor that requires a `Rectangle2D` be provided.  An appropriate transform will be created to make the gradient ellipse bounds match that of the provided rectangle.  I found the class documentation helpful:  [RadialGradientPaint API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RadialGradientPaint.html).  In particular, see the documentation for [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RadialGradientPaint.html#RadialGradientPaint(java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D,%20float[],%20java.awt.Color[],%20java.awt.MultipleGradientPaint.CycleMethod)).