# How to draw smooth dot in Java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

In Stellarium they draw stars natural, making them of different smooth size:

[image]

How to draw smooth dots of different sizes in Java? Like `Regor` star on the picture?

Comment: Perhaps [GradientPaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GradientPaint.html) is of interest.

Comment: Use a [`RadialGradientPaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/RadialGradientPaint.html) as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14170312/418556).